# add variable in glob2rx function in r

Tags: r

I want to get an expression and then put it in the glob2rx function, like:

```
glob2rx("*A*cfs*")
glob2rx("*B*cfs*")
glob2rx("*C*cfs*")
glob2rx("*D*cfs*")
```

because I want to use this expression to list file in folder, like:

```
list.files(pattern=glob2rx("*A*cfs*"))
```

I want to add a vector like:(looping through df)

```
 df <- c("A","B","C","D")
 ef <- paste0("\"","*",df[i],"*","cfs","*")
 list.files(pattern=glob2rx(ef))
```

But It did not work.

Could you give me some hints?

Comment: What does `i` stand for? Are you looping through `df`?

Comment: Yes. I want to loop through df. Sorry for this late reply.

Answer (score 1):

You're not closing with a `\"`. When you're looping, you can use

```
path <- getwd()
df <- c("A","B","C","D")
for(i in 1:length(df)){
  ef <- paste0("*",df[i],"*","cfs","*")
  list.files(path=path,glob2rx(pattern=ef))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it does not work. Return character(0).

Comment: Ah yes. Removed quotation marks and added path. That works here locally

Comment: Which quotation marks should I remove? Can you give me an example?  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I edited the answer, the quotation marks in the beginning, the `\"`